# Clustering prior to multiple linear regression?

Tags: clustering, multiple-regression

Assume I have:
N = 100, 5 continues predictor variables and 1 continues response.
Now I want to find a mapping between predictors and response using multiple linear regression.
Lets assume I know that my 100 samples consist of x subgroups, where for any subgroup I could find a match with very low MSE but for the whole population my MSE would increases   drastically.

Is there a standardized way to find out whether these subgroups exist?

Comment: You say you "know" the subgroups exist and then you say you want to "find out" if they do. Do you mean you want to find which subjects go into which cluster? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry i was not clear there, i want to assume i dont know subgroups exist and i want to find out whether they do or not.